# Canasta Question

Tags: canasta

If you pick up the pile of discards to meld, can you then use the entire rest of the pile in that same turn or do you have to wait until your next turn to use the rest of the pile?

Comment: Thank you!  It seems like you should have to wait a round like you do with the extra three cards you receive after your initial meld.

Comment: Welcome to [boardgames.se]! Your last comment seems to be a reply to the answer; it's better to post it as a comment *there* instead of under your question.

Comment: “The extra three cards you received after your initial meld”. That is not a rule I have heard of. Are you playing Classic or American Canasta?

Answer (score 1):

You can always meld any cards you have available to meld on your turn; it doesn’t matter if you just picked them up from the discard pile this turn or if you already had them.

Do note that cards from the discard pile, other than the top card, cannot be included in your initial meld for determining if you meet the minimum point requirement. But after that initial meld and you pick up the rest of the pile, you can continue to meld whatever you want.

> A player may meld as many cards as they please, of one rank or different ranks, forming new melds or adding cards to previous melds.

https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/